# Django equivalent to SQLAlchemy ORM events

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlalchemy

Is there a built-in equivalent, or library, that matches the features of [SQLAlchemy ORM events](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html) for the Django ORM?

I'm interested in hooking into the Django ORM like the [`before-compile`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.QueryEvents.before_compile) event allows. I want to modify a Django ORM queryset before it is executed.